# I need help adding VLANs to my non-VLAN home network

Tags: networking, wireless-router, switch, vlan

Currently, all my network devices don't support VLAN, with my setup being: 
 *(solid line means single LAN cable, dash-line means wireless connection)*
[image]

**Goal is to segregate my network into three VLANs:**

1. Main Devices *(TVs, PCs, phones, server)*
2. IoT Devices
3. Cameras

**Questions:**

1. Should I buy a separate router capable of VLAN, VPN, QoS, etc., or use my home server as a router to replace the ISP router?
2. Do I have to replace all my other router wifi and switch to VLAN-supported ones?
3. After meeting all the prerequisite network conditions, what should I do to connect my devices to different VLANs *(I only need some keywords, not a detailed tutorials)*?

Comment: There's more than one way to do vLANs, however the way I prefer is to use software vLANs configured on the router than don't require vLAN IDs to be configured on devices _(simply isn't necessary in a home setup)_. The home server wouldn't be recommended, unless running a router OS within a VM [OpenWrt, DD-WRT, Sophos UTM, pFsense, etc.]. Are any of your routers compatible with the opensource router OSes [OpenWrt](https://openwrt.org/toh/start) or [DD-WRT](https://dd-wrt.com/support/router-database/)? It's also never recommended to use an ISP router since they maintain remote access to your LAN

Comment: _(Cont'd...)_ Questions: **(1)** Use existing router if OpenWrt/DD-WRT supports it, or buy a router that is supported by either, and def change ISP to modem only | **(2)** Not if using software vLANs on a router without vLAN IDs; [example](https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/network/vlan/switch_configuration#assigning_vlan_ids_on_vlan-enabled_switch_hardware) of how OpenWrt does it, with vLANs 1 & 2 having no vLAN IDs, whereas vLAN 3 has a vLAN ID of 3 [`vid`] for LAN port 3 | **(3)** Configure router's interfaces via the WebUI or via SSH if using a Router OS - all clients connect as normal

Comment: This question might be better asked on a forum such as those on [servethehome.com](https://forums.servethehome.com/index.php). (I have no connection to them, no pun intended.)

Comment: If you want to split the network into VLANs for security, you might want to think about separating out the TVs if they don't need to communicate with the PCs and phones.

Comment: You might also want to think about how well the manufacturer will support the OS on the router/switch, e.g. a large mfr like Asus might drop support after, say, 7 years, but OpenWrt, [Tomato](https://www.cloudwards.net/tomato-vs-dd-wrt/), MikroTik (who also do hardware), etc., are likely to carry on for longer.

Comment: Hi @JW0914, thanks for the suggestion. Currently all of my routers are really old and doesnt support openwrt. I'm planing on replace them. But vlan supported router are really expensive here, so I think I'll grab a normal gigabits router and try openwrt.

Comment: Hi @AndrewMorton, really appreciate that forum recommendation. About TVs, I want to setup Plex and steam stuff from my PCs/ mobiles, so I think I'll keep it in the same vlan?

Comment: @JW0914 Also, can you explain why the home server is not recommended? I will run ESXi, and planing to set up a OpenWRT VM as my main router (replacement for the ISP router). Is it possible?

Comment: @vcth4nh Please see second part of the second sentence in my first comment. OpenWrt isn't really recommended for non-embedded devices _(IIRC, it doesn't run well on non-embedded devices)_. You'd be better off going with a full router OS like [pFsense](https://www.pfsense.org/download/) [BSD-based] or [Sophos Firewall](https://www.sophos.com/en-us/free-tools/sophos-xg-firewall-home-edition) [Linux-based)

Comment: @JW0914 Thanks for the clarification!